# Outlook Web Office AddIn - Save/Send button event handle using Custom Office AddIn (Taskpane) through code

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, office-addins, customtaskpane

I have created one office AddIn taskpane for new appointment/meeting in outlook calendar and I want to click send/save button from my custom AddIn using code.

I have created office AddIn using "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/quick-start?tabs=yeomangenerator" this link.

Check this link for screenshot.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dnx8a.png

**How can I explicitly fire a click event on the "Send" button of event calendar popup from my taskpane code?**

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @PV8
How can I explicitly fire a click event on the "Send" button of event calendar popup from my taskpane code?

Comment: @PV8 Please check this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dnx8a.png. I have added screenshot.